# Norm inequality on Complex Numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

For $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, it is true that $ 2 | z w| \leq |z|^2 + |w|^2 $. How does this imply the identity: $$|z+w|^2 \leq 2(|z|^2 + |w|^2 )? $$

Comment: Edited title to make it "inequality" rather than "identity." An identity is an equality - think the related word, "identical."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$|z+w|^2=|z^2+w^2+2zw|\leq|z|^2+|w|^2+2|zw|\leq 2(|z|^2+|w|^2)$$

Comment: Or from just substituting the inequality Peter gave.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
| z + w|^{2} & = & (z+w)(\overline{z+w})\\
& = & (z+w)(\overline{z} + \overline{w})\\
& = & z \cdot \overline{z} + z \overline{w} + w \overline{z} + w \overline{w} \\
& \le & |z|^{2} + |w|^{2} +|z \overline{w}| + |w \overline{z}|\\
& = & |z|^{2} + |w|^{2} + 2|z w|\\
& \le & 2(|z|^{2} + |w|^{2})\\
\end{eqnarray*}